# How do I loop through strings like they're column names?

Tags: r

Sample code

```
df <- read.csv('datafile.csv')
columnNames <- c('col1','col2')
```

I want to loop through `columnNames` and print their values. Basically, I want to get the same values I'd get if I entered into the console `df$col1` or `df$col2`. How do I do that?

Comment: You don't really need a loop.  Try `c(df[columnNames])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[` takes strings, where `$` doesn't.

```
for (cname in names(mtcars)) {
    print(mtcars[, cname])
}
```

See also:

```
> fortunes::fortune(343)
```

> Sooner or later most R beginners are bitten by this all too convenient shortcut. As an R newbie, think of R
>   as your bank account: overuse of $-extraction can lead to undesirable consequences. It's best to acquire the
>   '[[' and '[' habit early.   -- Peter Ehlers (about the use of $-extraction)
>         R-help (March 2013)

As @Buckminster points out, `[` is also vectorized, you might not need a loop:

```
cols = c("mpg", "disp", "cyl")
mtcars[, cols]
```

Comment: Or perhaps more simply (although the OP did request looping),`df[ ,columnNames]` will print the columns by default!

Comment: @Buckminster true, and true that whatever OP is doing a loop may not be necessary. However, I bet that this is a simplified case and OP's goal isn't simply to print the columns.